# How to add permission to SimulatorTrampoline to access specific folder

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode11, macos-catalina

macOS Catalina has presented a new way to access/denied files and folders.
Suddenly, i denied access request by `SimulatorTrampoline` to my `Documents` folder and can't get it back.
Also, **Security & Privacy > Privacy** `Full Disk Access` and `Files and Folders` doesn't contain any info about this denied request.
Basically, question is how to add this permission back? Maybe some sort of bash script can helps here or so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally got some workaround (i believe, `full access` only):

1. Find `SimulatorTrampoline.xpc` in `Finder`
2. Open `Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access`
3. Unlock to make changes
4. Drop the `SimulatorTrampoline.xpc` to apps area (it will be *invisible*)

   - Quit `SimulatorTrampoline.xpc` if needed
5. All permissions are set. Try to use simulator again

---

**UPD 13.10.2020**

How to find `SimulatorTrampoline.xpc`:

1. Open `Finder`
2. Type `SimulatorTrampoline.xpc` in search bar (right top corner)
3. Select `Search` option `This Mac`

[image]

Comment: Can you please file a feedback request on this and reply with the FB number? It should not be invisible.

Comment: Hi, @russbishop. What did you mean by "FB number"?

Comment: Hey, where should i found `SimulatorTrampoline.xpc` coz i don't have it :\\

Comment: Still, i couldn't found it :\,UH that's for Catalina only? coz I have Mojave!

Comment: Yes, sure, i'm using Catalina not a Mojave

Comment: Thanks, can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332302/how-to-save-files-in-simulator-xcode-11-3-1) maybe you can help!

Answer (score 4):

Find SimulatorTrampoline.xpc in Finder.
You have to include "System Files" in your criteria to search places like the user Library.

[image: Find]

path: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/SimulatorTrampoline.xpc

Answer (score 0):

I think this caused by MacOS permission for Xcode.

[image]

So, Just move files to `Documents` folder then try to drag into Simulator again. Worked for me.

Refer: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126307