# Error when pick/save the file in the simulator - Xcode 11.3.1?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have Mojave,
I'm trying to drag and drop the file "PDF" to the simulator Or download it online but not works!

And I got this annoying error

[image: shot]

I tried to add Xcode & simulator to list of `Security => privcy => Full Disk Access`

**Another issue**

When I pick any file from iCloud i got this error too :\

> couldn't communicate with a helper application